# Jquery UI Framework

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery

Thanks for looking into this.

I'm looking to build a framework of apps which can be extended by third party developers.

The goal is to load each frame via ajax - I need to know if there is a framework which can be help me position and resize various widgets just like this one.

Example screenshot
http://tour.netvibes.com/private.php

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Not completely sure what the question is... but:

http://jqueryui.com/

Draggable/droppable as well as jqueryui dialog should help you create and position widgets as in your question.

Answer (score 0):

If you do 'view source' on the page you have linked, you can see that the page uses Mootools.
Appears to be some kind of Javascript framework.

http://mootools.net/

Additionally, you could follow Mark's advice and go with jQuery, which is a widely-used, mature framework that offers great functionality.

Comment: Thank you for responding. I am aware of mootools and jquery. However, the position of widgets are all dynamic if you notice. They snap to the positions correctly which is very interesting. 

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with rmk and Mark about jQuery being a great framework!
For the ajax stuff it works well and is really easy to get into work.

For the UI part you can try the "standard" jQueryUI, which is well structured and easily themed, but by now it has a limited set of things. You have all you need to build widgets, but you don't have ready-to-use stuff like panels, layouts and so on..

If you need more, besides those said above, try looking at [jQuery EasyUI](http://www.jeasyui.com/), which has a lot more of things (for instance a ["panel" extension](http://www.jeasyui.com/extension/portal.php) to put widgets inside).

They are both based on jQuery.